# A basis of a null space of a binary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

An $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is called a binary matrix if all entries of $A$ are either $0$ or $1$. Also, a vector $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a trinary vector if all entries of $\mathbf{x}$ are either $-1$, $0$, or $1$.

I want to prove/disprove the following assertion.

> Given an $m \times n$ binary matrix $A$, it is always possible to construct a basis for a null space of $A$ with trinary vectors only.

I played with matlab, and didn't find any counter example at least for comparatively small $m,\, n$. Any idean would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a counterexample:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

The lines of this $3\times 4$ matrix being linearly independent, the kernel is of dimension 1. It is generated by the following vector

\begin{bmatrix} 
-2 \\
-1 \\
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}  .

Therefore there is no trinary vector generating the null space of that binary matrix.

The question of determining which conditions on $A$ imply the existence of a trinary basis seems a very interesting (and non-trivial) task. Any ideas in this direction are welcome...!

Comment: Here's another formulation: by adding rows/cols of 0's, we may assume that $m=n$. We may then view the matrix as the incidence matrix of a simple directed graph with loops, and you want eigenvectors of this graph with values in $\{0, \pm 1\}$. (That is, assign a weight in $\{0, \pm 1\}$ to each vertex such that the sum of incoming weights at distance $1$ is $0$ for each vertex.) If you assume that the matrix is symmetric and that there are no loops, and weights are in $\{ \pm 1\}$, then this is discussed in this paper: https://amc-journal.eu/index.php/amc/article/viewFile/1021/982

Answer (score 0):

A family of binary matrices for which the answer is positive is presented [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.14062), see Proposition 3.4 on page 20. The family of trinary vectors thus obtained define an hyperplane arrangement associated to the [permutahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron).